# variables naming convention for abbreviation in Python

Tags: python, readability, coding-style

I read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and [abbreviations for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358840/which-abbreviations-should-we-use-for-python-variable-names), and I have question regarding the variable name itself.
I'm familiar with the famous variable abbreviations, For example, :

1. `str` for string
2. `cnt` for counter
3. `cfg` for configuration

It's came into my mind after thought about an appropriate name for a variable that contain first instruction, I thought about `fisr_inst` or `first_instr` or even `first_instruction` but couldn't find any document regarding this in Python.
but is there a table, or a list of all those abbreviation conventions in python? did I miss it?

EDIT - **I didn't asked for appropriate name for "my variable name", I asked if there a table or list that contain some abbreviation for common use in python**

Comment: Who cares?  `first_instr` is certainly acceptable and good enough.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, for adding readability to the code, even if `first_instruction` is not too long name for variable, I already saw in code abbreviation that took me some time to decode, and I don't want others to spend time in decoding my abbreviation

Comment: Then don't abbreviate.  This kind of question is off topic for SO because it is opinion-driven.

Comment: str is a builtin function that should not be shadowed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, my question wasn't about `first_instruction` name, but for general table or list, with common abbreviations for variable names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicit and verbose is the recommended standard as far as naming things is concerned. EXTREMELY common abbreviations that are impossible to be mistaken are used to shorten line length, but don't think too far into those.

i for index, j for secondary index (in a 2D array), f for file, del for delete, str for string, cnt for count, cfg for config, prod for production, dist for distribution, fact for factorial, etc.

I don't know what use you have for `first_instruction`, but I wouldn't try to shorten either word - that is a solid variable name.

edit: My opinion has changed on the matter so I figured I'd share. I've now worked on distributed teams where contributing members have learned English later or are still learning English. Nowadays, I simply never abbreviate because I was only doing it to cut a few characters anyways ‍♂️